# Morris Chart is Missing Half Part

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

I used morris chart in my application project to show some details about quantity of sales.

After executing the AJAX request, the chart is only showing half part. Here's the syntax:

```
var chartBahan = Morris.Bar ({
    element: 'morris-analytics-bahan',
    xkey: '2',
    ykeys: ['3'],
    labels: ['Quantity Bahan'],
    resize: false,
    gridEnabled: true
}); 

//getting the morris chart over bahan and karakteristik
function getBahanPotensial(kode){
    //ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async: false,
        url:"<%= request.getContextPath()%>/GenerateListBahanPotensial",
        data:{
            kode:kode
        },
        success: function(data){
            chartBahan.setData($.parseJSON(data));
            chartBahan.redraw();
        },
        error:function(msg){
            alert("Data Failed to Analyze" + msg); 
        }
    }); 
}

var chartKarakter = new Morris.Bar ({
    element: 'morris-analytics-karakter',
    xkey: '2',
    ykeys: ['3'],
    labels: ['Karakter Quantity'],
    resize: true
});

function getKarakterPotensial(kode){
    //ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async: false,
        url:"<%= request.getContextPath()%>/GenerateListKarakterPotensial",
        data:{
            kode:kode
        },
        success:function(data){
            chartKarakter.setData($.parseJSON(data));
            chartKarakter.redraw();
        },
        error:function(msg){
            alert("Data Failed to Analyze" + msg); 
        }
    });
}
```

I execute the above function from another function let say doProcess()

```
function sendRequest(thecode){
    if(thecode === ""){ alert("Tolong Input Kode Produk");}
    else {
        var kodebarang = thecode;
    }
    //executing AJAX call.                   
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        async: false,
        url:"<%= request.getContextPath()%>/GenerateAnalytics",
        data:{
            kodebarang:kodebarang
        },
        success:function(msg){
            $('#result_analysis').show();
            $('#navigation_button').show();
            new Morris.Bar ({
                element: 'morris-analytics-bar',
                data: $.parseJSON(msg),
                xkey: '1',
                ykeys: ['2', '3'],
                labels: ['Sales Area', 'Tingkat Penjualan'],
                barRatio: 0.4,
                xLabelAngle: 0,
                hideHover: 'auto'
            });

            //execute the morris chart others !! PENTING
            var kodeb = $('#bahan_id').val();
            var kodek = $('#karakteristik_id').val();
            getBahanPotensial(kodeb);
            getKarakterPotensial(kodek);
        },
        error:function(msg){
            alert("Data Failed to Analyze" + msg); 
        }
    });
}
```

but the problem is, when i create Morris Chart in Success Callback

```
success:function(msg){
    $('#result_analysis').show();
    $('#navigation_button').show();
    new Morris.Bar ({
        element: 'morris-analytics-bar',
        data: $.parseJSON(msg),
        xkey: '1',
        ykeys: ['2', '3'],
        labels: ['Sales Area', 'Tingkat Penjualan'],
        barRatio: 0.4,
        xLabelAngle: 0,
        hideHover: 'auto'
    });
```

The chart is properly showing. Here's the screen shot:
[image: properly showing]

But the other chart when i use template for charting (outside the success callback) the chart is BROKEN

here's the screenshot

[image: error chart]

then, i have dropdown list to regenerate the chart based on specific parameter, the chart is properly showing (all data show) BUT the chart is only half PAGE. here's the screenshot:

[image: right half]

Is there any ideas what going on?

**UPDATE**

What I mean template is code like this:

```
var chartBahan = Morris.Bar ({
    element: 'morris-analytics-bahan',
    xkey: '2',
    ykeys: ['3'],
    labels: ['Quantity Bahan'],
    resize: false,
    gridEnabled: true
});
```

and the method to call the template is

```
success:function(data){
    chartBahan.setData($.parseJSON(data));
    chartBahan.redraw();
},
```

The RIGHT chart is the FIRST Screenshot. It's wider than the other two.

**UPDATED 2**

still getting error on charts created by Morris :(

here's the screenshot.

[image: error graph again!]

Comment: Where is 'outside the success callback' if you draw all 3 charts inside 3 success callbacks? What do you mean by the word 'template', where is it in the code? Also the last screenshot looks ok to me, but if something is wrong, write more details how it should look.

Answer (score 4):

I solved that issue by setting the width of the svg element to 100% in css

```
svg{
  width: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two last charts from your example threw lots of errors in the console of Google Chrome (you can open it by pressing F12).

The reason is that the `data` property is required when you call `Morris.Bar({ data: ... })`, but in you example you didn't have this property. So you should completely remove your declarations like `var chartBahan = Morris.Bar (...` and replace the success callback with this code:

```
function getBahanPotensial(kode){
    $.ajax({
    ...
        success: function(data){
            if (window.chartBahan) {
                chartBahan.setData($.parseJSON(data));
                // chartBahan.redraw(); // useless call, it can be removed
            } else {
                window.chartBahan = Morris.Bar ({
                    element: 'morris-analytics-bahan',
                    data: $.parseJSON(data),
                    xkey: '2',
                    ykeys: ['3'],
                    labels: ['Quantity Bahan'],
                    resize: false,
                    gridEnabled: true
                }); 
            }
        }
    ...
    }); 
}
```

In my code I check whether the global variable `window.chartBahan` exists and if it doesn't - I create a new chart; otherwise I call `setData` and the chart updates itself automatically.

Also you haven't posted your HTML mark-up, it may have issues as well. I used this HTML code and it worked fine:

```
<body>
    <div id="morris-analytics-bar" style="height: 250px;"></div>
    <div id="morris-analytics-bahan" style="height: 250px;"></div>
    <div id="morris-analytics-karakter" style="height: 250px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: i haven't tried your method but i will tell u what the result is. thanks for your answer.

Comment: i have tried the method and my chart is NOT showing Properly. see the updated section again. thanks.

Comment: it seems that morris chart cannot render and calculate the width and height of divs so it always broken. i've see my chrome console and throwing an error `Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute width=“-1”`

Comment: @randytan Probably you should set exact height and width of yor div elements. For example `style="height: 300px; width: 500px"`. It seems your elements have 0 width.

Comment: div elements are set to `style="height: auto;width: auto;"` but the problem is when it's set to auto, the morris chart is very small. Then i change the style into `style="height: 100%;width: 100%;"` but the problem still persist, and the chart when triggered twice showing half part only.

Comment: @randytan If it works with width/height `auto` or in numbers, then all the problems are because of width and height set to "100%". The container or its parent should have a real height.

Comment: when it setup in numbers, the morris chart is broken too. i think the problem is persist in some rendering function in morris. what do you think?

Comment: @randytan rendering works ok for correct data and correct div elements. Check in chrome developer tools what height and width your div elements have before rendering. Also check the data returned from AJAX, I used test JSON like `[ { 2: 'Apples', 3: 140 }, { 2: 'Oranges', 3: 80 } ]`, but your JSON data may look different.

Comment: Explicityly setting the height for the div element works for me, thanks @vortexwolf

Answer (score 0):

**//Java script code**

```
Morris.Line({
      element: 'hero-area',
      data: getdata("<?php echo base_url('user/getYearlPremiumuser');?>") ,
      xkey: 'Year',
      parseTime: false,
      ykeys: ['Teacher', 'Student'],

      labels: ['Teacher', 'Student'],
      hideHover: 'false',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 5,
      lineColors: ['#4a8bc2', '#ff6c60'],
      fillOpacity:7,
      smooth: true
  });
```

[********//php code ( code codeigniter)********](http://hirenmakwana701.blogspot.in/)

```
  public function getYearlPremiumuser()
    {

         $teacherArray={ y: '2014', a: 50, b: 90},
  { y: '2015', a: 65,  b: 75},
  { y: '2016', a: 50,  b: 50},
  { y: '2017', a: 75,  b: 60},
  { y: '2018', a: 80,  b: 65},
  { y: '2019', a: 90,  b: 70},
  { y: '2020', a: 100, b: 75},
  { y: '2021', a: 115, b: 75},
  { y: '2022', a: 120, b: 85},
  { y: '2023', a: 145, b: 85},
  { y: '2024', a: 160, b: 95}
        for($i=0;$i<count($teacherArray);$i++)
        {
            $temp=array();
            $temp=  array_merge($teacherArray[$i],$studentarray[$i]);
            $finalResultArray[]=$temp;

        }
        echo json_encode($finalResultArray); 
    }
```

[click here to know more](http://hirenmakwana701.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue using Morris.js and Angular2 - the problem in my case was that I use in DIV with chart the *ngIf='showChart' (or [hidden]='!showChart')  - and when I set up chart, the showChar=false so the div doesn't exist. In my case I read date periodic in every 1min so at first dataLoad i see nothing, after second dataLoad i see half/part of chart). So I fix this by (typescript):

```
showchart = true;
setTimeout( () => { this.setUpChart() }, 1 );
```

And it works :)